# element inside <demo-snippet> is not cloned/projected properly only in IE11

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

I think the element is not being projected properly in IE11. Look at the following example:

```
<body unresolved>

  <p>If this demo works correctly, you should be able to see the message <code>"Hello there. Hola!"</code></p>

  <p>
    This works as expected in all browsers except Internet Explorer 11 (maybe 10, although I didn't test). The issue is that when I assign helloElement.value, helloElement is not the same element that is being appended to the dome after is projected inside
    the &lt;demo-snippet&gt;.
  </p>

  <demo-snippet>
    <template is="dom-bind">
      <hello-element></hello-element>

      <script>
        var helloElement = document.querySelector('hello-element');
        helloElement.value = 'Hola!';

        // Wait enough time to make sure demo-snipper is rendered properly
        setTimeout(function() {
          console.log(helloElement === document.querySelector('hello-element')) // this is true in all browsers. In IE11 is false.
        }, 3000)
      </script>
    </template>

  </demo-snippet>
</body>
```

What it happens is that the value assigned in `helloElement.value` is copied into the projected element inside the demo-snippet element in all browsers except in IE11. That means, if you add a ready handler and you do

```
ready: function () {
   console.log(this.value) // --> 'Hola!' except IE11, that is ''
}
```

Is this a bug in Polymer or demo-snippet when projecting my code inside? or when is attached to the dom? I really have no clue :(

You can play with my example in this Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/5UBCDjqC0A8k6HcaHnIJ?p=preview

Comment: why have you not set value from markup?

Comment: This is an example to show the error. In my real code, I have a big array of data, so passing in the markup is not an option. But thanks.

Comment: In that case you can fetch i from json file using an ajax request

Comment: @jhuesos a big array of data can be passed into a model which then uses `dom-repeat` elements (ppssibly nested) to put it into the mark up.  I have a calendar element which displays a complete month's calendar, which details lists of appointments in each day. and little graphs of how full the lists are in each day.  All of the data is retrieved in a single ajax request to the server and all of it is then added to an Object in my elements properties.  The entire calendar is displayed using mark up from that single object.

Comment: Couldn't fit my full answer on one comment.  document.querySelector() is working with shadow dom and I think works differently depending on what is polyfilled or not.  If you insist on working in the dom (and as I said in the previous comment it shouldn't be necessary) look at the Polymer developers guide at the Polymer.dom() manipulation routines.

Comment: The point of my question is not how to pass an array of data to a component. What I am trying to understand is why in all browsers, the element is projected inside the element and in IE/Edge, apparently, the element is not projected/move, it is only clone. That is what I am trying to understand and figure out, it might be a bug with Polymer shady dom in IE/Edge.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently IE is stricter with this. You need to call `element.setAttribute` instead of just adding it in the object.

This will ensure that polymer picks up de default value as an attribute.